# Same coefficient interpretation between first difference and original data?

Tags: regression, data-transformation, stationarity, lags

Assume we have 500 observations, each representing the price in dollars of a rare Tibetan feline (P) measured at the end of each month. Then we take the first differences and arrive at a new set of data, call it P’, representing the absolute change in P for each month, relative to the previous month. I.e. P at month t minus P at month t-1.

I also have 500 observations representing the number of cat ladies in the world at the end of the month (x). Again, take the first differences and we get x’ which represents the change in x for each month, relative to the last month - just like P’ works.

If I run a regression predicting P’ using x’, then I get a beta estimate of B = 2. So, the interpretation is “for every 1 unit rise in the change in x, I expect a $2 rise in the change in P.” But this is such a messy interpretation…

Now, I’ve been reading that we can take a leap and forget the above interpretation entirely and just act like we are talking about the original data. So, I can use B to mean “for every 1 unit rise in x, I expect a 2 dollar rise in P.” Or, equivalently “for every extra cat lady, the price of this rare Tibetan feline rises by $2.”

People are arguing over this elsewhere… is this true?

Comment: The interpretation of the coefficient on $x$ is exactly the same when the equation is in levels or in differences. But the estimation will typically produce different coefficients, so perhaps you are getting hung up on that.

Comment: So if I transform two series x and y to their respective differences and get a regression coefficient of 2, I can say “a one unit rise in x implies a 2 rise in y?” And I think I see what you mean by “the estimation will typically produce difference coefficients.” So when we find the coefficient for the differenced data, we are effectively going all in and saying the actual population coefficient is the coefficient we found with the differenced regression?? I hope I understand that! ;(

Comment: Yes, the tranformation is typically done to enable you to estimate the population slope, while retaining the interpretation.

Comment: Great thank you. I just did the simple derivation to prove to myself. Thank you dimitriy.

Comment: You can post that and accept your own answer.

Comment: Will the correlation also be the same. I can’t quite figure that out now…

Comment: Correlation between what?

Comment: Apologies. Can I take the correlation coefficient from the differenced regression to be the true correlation coefficient? I suppose what you’re saying is that all values I get from the differenced regression model are taken to be the true values describing the relationship between my non transformed data? Coefficient, correlation etc etc?

Comment: Sorry for repeat questions btw… I just can’t find anywhere that clearly says this so I’m getting all nervous to use the differenced data.

Comment: And this video says they are no the same beta. Now I’m horribly confused. https://youtu.be/eQYZK9Ah7TY

Comment: I am not sure that is at odds with what I wrote in my first comment. That video is about estimation. The reason that $\beta$ and $\delta$ don’t align is that the first model’s error creates issues. If you fix that by differencing, the problem goes away and you recover the true effect.

Comment: So I’m a super easy situation where you have two series, you first difference them, you regress the first differenced data. That beta is used as an estimate for the level data beta. His scenario is somehow different from my situation. Yes?

Comment: He is fitting the model in levels in addition to differences and then comparing the coefficients.

Comment: I see my friend thank you. I will use the beta I get from the differenced data to be the same beta for levels. Thank you so much for the warm interaction. Very helpful. I owe you a beer or two when I’m in the bay next.